# mutation observer for a particular div

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have around a large html data, around 200k data with sub details images and all.

The problem i am facing when i try to set the html content that i get, i am getting browser stuck issue. So what i am trying to do is i am writing an observer which checks for that particular div, whether all the html has been added. Then i need to disable the loader so the user can use

What i have tried so far

```
var isHtmlAppending = true



function mutate(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation, index) {
    if(index === mutations.length - 1){
      isHtmlAppending = false
   }
  });
}


  var target = document.getElementById('container')
  var observer = new MutationObserver( mutate );
  var config = { characterData: true, attributes: false, childList: false, 
  subtree: true };

  observer.observe(target, config);



$.ajax({
  // call the api and get the html data
  success: (function(data){
     $("#container").html = data.renderedHtml
  })
})
```

How to make this working ?, any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The `childList` property in the config must be set to `true` in order to find new elements added.

Here's how you can use the MutationObserver to find the element that you are looking for:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("target");
var numDivs = 0;

var btn = document.getElementById("add-div");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = "new-div-" + numDivs;
  newDiv.innerHtml = "New Div";
  target.appendChild(newDiv);
  numDivs++;
});

var mo = new MutationObserver(function(list, _o) {
  var numItems = list.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    var m = list[i];
    if (m.type === "childList") {
      var node = m.addedNodes[0];
      if (node.id == "new-div-0") { // Example target id
        console.log("I found the element I was looking for!");
      }
    }
  }
});

mo.observe(target, {
  childList: true
});
```

```css
#target>div {
  background: #a33;
  margin: 2px 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
  <button id="add-div">Add div</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am stuck at the snippet which i have posted on OP, can you guide me on that one as i am newbie to this jquery